# i18n library by (api.i18nexus) do not work , in fact useTranslation do not work?You can use the method without api by i18nexus for react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-i18next

In Windows 10, I'm using react-router-dom 5.2.0 and react-redux 7.2.5 and react 17.0.2 and axios 0.21.4 and WebStorm 2023.1.3 IDE and PyCharm Community Edition 2023.2 and djangorestframework 3.14.0 and Django 4.2.4 and djangorestframework-simplejwt 5.3.0.

**Note 1**: I wanted to create a **multi-language** web site using API and with the i18n library, *but the process of text translation is not done*, in fact, `my const {t} = useTranslation()` does not work, now where is the bug and problem of my program please direct me.

**Note 2**:Now that for some reason the `api` is not working, can someone implement the method **without api** and **offline** through the **i18nexus library** for me in the **answer**, thank you.

**Consider - src/i18n.js**:

```
import i18next from "i18next";
import HttpBackend from "i18next-http-backend";
import LanguageDetector from "i18next-browser-languagedetector";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";

const apiKey = ""; 
const loadPath = `https://api.i18nexus.com/project_resources/translations/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json?api_key=${apiKey}`;

i18next
    .use(HttpBackend)
    .use(LanguageDetector)
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .init({
        fallbackLng: "en",

        ns: ["default"],
        defaultNS: "default",

        supportedLngs: ["en","fa","ar","fr","de","ru"],

        backend: {
            loadPath: loadPath
        }
    })
```

**Consider - src/App.js**:

```
import Header from "./components/Header"
import Footer from "./components/Footer"
import HomeScreen from "./screens/home_screen";
import ProductScreen from "./screens/product_screen";
import CartScreen from "./screens/cart_screen";
import LoginScreen from "./screens/login_screen";
import RegisterScreen from "./screens/register_screen";
import CompleteUserInformationScreen from "./screens/complete_user_information_screen";
import ProfileScreen from "./screens/profile_screen";
import SuccessUserActivationScreen from "./screens/success_user_activation_screen";
import ExpiredUserActivationScreen from "./screens/expired_user_activation_screen";
import InvalidUserActivationScreen from "./screens/invalid_user_activation_screen";
import PaymentScreen from "./screens/payment_screen";
import ShippingScreen from "./screens/shipping_screen";
import PlaceOrderScreen from "./screens/place_order_screen";
import ManagerLoginScreen from "./screens/manager_login_screen";
import OrderScreen from "./screens/order_screen";
import ManagerRoom from "./screens/manager_room";
import EditAllowCommentScreen from "./screens/edit_allow_comment_screen";
import EditAllowReplyScreen from "./screens/edit_allow_reply_screen";
import { BrowserRouter as Router , Route} from "react-router-dom";
import DoYouDeleteAccount from "./screens/do_you_delete_account";
import React , {useState , useEffect , Suspense} from "react";
import { useTranslation , Trans } from "react-i18next";
import SearchBar from "./components/SearchBar";
import ProductsInOneCategory from "./screens/products_in_one_category";
import ProductsInOneTag from "./screens/products_in_one_tag";
import ActiveOrInActiveProduct from "./screens/active_or_inactive_product";
import DeleteProduct from "./screens/delete_product";


function App() {
    const supportedLanguages = [ { value: "", text: "Options" },{value:"en",text:"ENGLISH"},{value:"fa" , text:"PERSIAN"},{value:"ar",text:"ARABIC"},{value:"fr",text:"FRENCH"},{value :"de",text:"GERMAN"},{value:"ru",text:"RUSSIAN"}];
    const { t , i18n  } = useTranslation();
    const [lang, setLang] = useState("en");
    // This function put query that helps to
    // change the language

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setLang(() => e.target.value);

        let loc = "http://localhost:3000/";
        window.location.replace(
            loc + "?lng=" + e.target.value
        );
    };

  return (

    <Router>
        <div className="row p-2 m-1" >

            <div className="col-12 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between bg-info text-white" >
                <div className="col-form-label text-white" for="langChoose" >{t("select language")}</div>
                <select value={lang} onChange={handleChange}>
                    {supportedLanguages.map((item) => {
                        return (
                            <option

                                key={item.value}
                                value={item.value}
                            >
                                {item.text}
                            </option>
                        );
                    })}
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <Header />
        <SearchBar />
        <main>
            <div className="container py-3 p-5" >
                <Route path='/' component={HomeScreen} exact />
                <Route path='/product/:id' component={ProductScreen} />
                <Route path='/cart/:id?' component={CartScreen} />
                <Route path='/login' component={LoginScreen} />
                <Route path="/register" component={RegisterScreen} />
                <Route path="/complete_user_information" component={CompleteUserInformationScreen} />
                <Route path="/profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
                <Route path="/success" component={SuccessUserActivationScreen} />
                <Route path="/expired" component={ExpiredUserActivationScreen} />
                <Route path="/invalid" component={InvalidUserActivationScreen} />
                <Route path="/do_you_want_delete_it" component={DoYouDeleteAccount} />
                <Route path="/shipping" component={ShippingScreen} />
                <Route path="/payment" component={PaymentScreen} />
                <Route path="/placeorder" component={PlaceOrderScreen} />
                <Route path="/order/:id" component={OrderScreen} />
                <Route path="/Manager" component={ManagerLoginScreen} />
                <Route path="/manager_room" component={ManagerRoom} />
                <Route path="/edit_allow_or_delete_comment/:id" component={EditAllowCommentScreen} />
                <Route path="/edit_allow_or_delete_reply/:id" component={EditAllowReplyScreen} />
                <Route path="/products_in_one_category/:id" component={ProductsInOneCategory} />
                <Route path="/products_in_one_tag/:id" component={ProductsInOneTag} />
                <Route path="/change_product_status/active_or_inactive_product/:id" component={ActiveOrInActiveProduct} />
                <Route path="/delete_product/:id" component={DeleteProduct} />
            </div>

        </main>

        <Footer />
    </Router>

  );
}

export default App;
```

**Note**: I run `npm i i18next i18next-http-backend i18next-browser-languagedetector react-i18next --no-audit --no-fund` in command prompt, and my source is [Multi-Language Support in ReactJS - www.geeksforgeeks.org](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multi-language-support-in-reactjs/).

**point**: Consider `<div className="col-form-label text-white" for="langChoose" >{t("select language")}</div>`, this function `t("select language")` does not work.

**Consider - package.json**:

```json
{
    "name": "frontend",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",
        "@sasmeee/ip-locator": "^1.1.8",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
        "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
        "audit": "^0.0.6",
        "axios": "^0.21.4",
        "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
        "dayjs": "^1.11.10",
        "fusion-plugin-csrf-protection": "^3.4.7",
        "google-map-react": "^2.2.1",
        "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.19.1",
        "i18next": "^23.8.2",
        "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^7.2.0",
        "i18next-http-backend": "^2.4.3",
        "jwt-check-expiration": "^1.0.5",
        "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
        "next-i18next": "^15.2.0",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-bootstrap": "^2.9.2",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        "react-i18next": "^14.0.2",
        "react-ip-location": "^1.0.24",
        "react-ipgeolocation": "^1.4.0",
        "react-password-checklist": "^1.4.3",
        "react-public-ip": "^1.0.0",
        "react-redux": "^7.2.5",
        "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.2.23",
        "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.25.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
        "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
        "redux": "^4.1.1",
        "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
        "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
        "use-debounce": "^10.0.0",
        "web-vitals": "^1.1.2",
        "xregexp": "^5.1.1"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
            "react-app",
            "react-app/jest"
        ]
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    }
}
```

I hope, I don't make a typo - please help to answer.

Comment: I am sure you have a real API key and `const apiKey = "api key";` is just a placeholder value you used for asking

Comment: No, it is because the API key does not go down @Davi

Comment: @Davi I'm sure you weren't encouraging the user to expose their API Key as they now have... Saman, I suggest using the Contact Us link at the bottom of the page to ask for your API key to be expunged from the edit history of the question. You were right in not including it in the first place, and now anyone can see it by looking at the edit history.

Comment: Is that an actual API key?

Comment: Now that for some reason the api is not working, can someone implement the method without api and offline through the i18nexus library for me in the answer, thank you